# Swift json dynamic key parsing for json

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dynamic, dynamic-keyword

I have json response where only just one key name change rest is same and want to parse without duplicating same struct again.

```
"attributes": {
  "symbol":"EUR",
  "name":"Euro",
  "precision":2,             
}
    
"attributes":{
  "symbol":"EUR",
  "name":"Euro",
  "precision_for_fiat_price":2,  
}
```

How can handle this precision key dynamically in json parsing

Comment: So the key could be either `"precision"` or `"precision_for_fiat_price"`? Could it be anything else?

Comment: @Sweeper yes either "precision" or "precision_for_fiat_price"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `keyDecodingStrategy`.

Essentially, you write some logic that checks whether the current coding key path matches some criteria, and if it does, map that key to the `precision` key.

For example:

```
struct Root : Codable {
    let attributes: Attributes
}

struct Attributes : Codable {
    let symbol: String
    let name: String
    let precision: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case symbol
        case name
        case precision
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({
    keys in

    // This will decode every precision_for_fiat_price key in the json as "precision".
    // You might not want this. 
    // Make this criteria stricter if you need to. An example is shown below
    if keys.last?.stringValue == "precision_for_fiat_price" {
        return Attributes.CodingKeys.precision
    }

    // this will only decode those precision_for_fiat_price that have "attribute" as their parent as "precision"
//    if stringPath.suffix(2) == ["attributes", "precision_for_fiat_price"] {
//        return Attributes.CodingKeys.precision
//    }
    return keys.last!
})
let json = """
{
    "attributes":{
                  "symbol":"EUR",
                  "name":"Euro",
                  "precision_for_fiat_price":2
                  
     }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
let decoded = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: json)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just decode json model like this:

```swift
let json = """
{
  "attributes": {
     "symbol":"EUR",
     "name":"Euro",
     "precision_for_fiat_price":2 // or "precision": 2
  }
}
"""
```

You can create `Decodable` struct:

```
struct WrapperModel: Decodable { // any model
    var attributes: Attributes
}

struct Attributes : Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let name: String
    var precision: Int = 0
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case symbol
        case name
        case precision
        case precisionAnother = "precision_for_fiat_price"
        // you can write any types of key here
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        symbol = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .symbol)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        if let precisionValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .precision) {
            precision = precisionValue
        }
        if let precisionValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .precisionAnother) {
            precision = precisionValue
        }
    }
}
```

You can test it with:

```
let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let attributes = try decoder.decode(WrapperModel.self, from: jsonData)
    print(attributes)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please say if your code will be relevant in cases when server always generates different keys in response? For example, some jsonObj has   "tiered_prices": {
            "100": "329990",
            "200": "324990"
        },  another may be    "tiered_prices": {
            "300": "329990",
            "500": "324990"
        } but I don't know keys names beforehand